# Changed Discovery Behavior of Alternative MinGW in Eclipse-CDT(8.2) Bundled in Kepler-version(4.3)

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

When using an **alternative** MinGW version like e.g., [mingwbuilds-gcc/g++-4.8.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.8.1-release-posix-sjlj-rev3.7z/download), the [CDT(8.2) bundled in the latest Kepler-version(4.3)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-cpp-kepler-R-win32.zip) is not able to discover it as a MinGW tool chain.
This behavior is introduced with this latest release.
The MinGW discovery process works fine on such an alternative MinGW in previous releases like [Juno-SR2 bundled with CDT(8.1.1)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-cpp-juno-SR2-win32.zip) and so on.
Indeed, there's a workaround to this problem by simply adding a file entry named `mingw32-gcc.exe` in MinGW `bin` directory (e.g., by issuing `touch c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe`)

I've tried to find some documentation of the CDT tool chain discovery process, especially for this latest CDT 8.2-version, without any success.
So, my question is: Where to find such documentation - if any?
Or, can anybody explain?
Many thanks in advance!